# Inconsistency between console.log, Object.keys and Object.getOwnPropertyNames

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am currently using Mongoose, however all these hidden keys are driving me crazy and is disrupting my workflow when these keys are popping up out of nowhere. Here is my code - it's simply logging the docs from the find function:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.log)
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
    var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' })
    fluffy.save((err, fluffy) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        Kitten.find({}, (err, docs) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; ++i) {
                const doc = docs[i]
                console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames ', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(doc))
                console.log('Object.keys ', Object.keys(doc))
                console.log(doc)
                console.log('--')
            }
        })
    })
})
```

And one of the docs that's logged is [image]

Why are the keys shown by console log in neither `.keys` nor `.getOwnPropertyNames`? The console.log output is the one that reflects what's actually in the MongoDB document.

Edit: Edited to use more reasonable code

Comment: Try to use `console.dir(doc);` it might give you more variables to work with

Comment: Unfortunately console.dir outputs the same thing as console.log so no new information there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docs` is a list of Mongoose document objects. They don't have fields available for enumeration, there are accessors defined that make them available as `doc.fieldName`.

There are document [`toObject`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) and [`toJSON`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON) methods to convert document object to plain object when needed.

The actual problem here is that since document object aren't needed, they shouldn't be queried. Plain objects can be retrieved with `lean`.

```
    Kitten.find({}).lean().exec((err, docs) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; ++i) {
            const doc = docs[i]
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: This was it! I had no idea that each `doc` was an `instanceof mongoose.Document`. I feel the documentation on Mongoose doesn't clarify this where its applicable, nor does it blatantly distinguish the difference between Mongoose's document and the MongoDB document that I'm supposed to be getting through the find function. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, it's strange to see how often callbacks are still used because Mongoose supports promises for a long time. They result in much more straightforward control flow, especially with async/await.

Comment: Probably because nearly all the examples on the documentation uses callbacks - but agreed

Answer (score 0):

The results you get from "find" are cursers. You need to use "toArray" to load the document to RAM.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', mongoose.Schema({ name: String }));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.log)
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
    var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' })
    fluffy.save((err, fluffy) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        Kitten.find({}).toArray((err, doc) => {
                console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames ', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(doc))
                console.log('Object.keys ', Object.keys(doc))
                console.log(doc)
                console.log('--')
        })
    })
})
```